# How do I enlarge a Framework Element by Touch Manipulation in Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, touch, uwp, windows-10-mobile

On iPhone and Android it is possible to zoom into a picture by sliding two fingers apart on screen. I would like to do something similar on Windows Universal Apps, but instead of zooming I want to enlarge the framework element. Is this a Manipulation Event?

Update: Yes I only want to enlarge the specific UIElement by fingers.

Currently my object is set up to translate with this event:

```
  private void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (!(fe.RenderTransform is TransformGroup))
        {
            TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
            TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
            tt.X = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            tt.Y = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
            ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
            st.ScaleX = e.Cumulative.Scale;
            st.ScaleY = e.Cumulative.Scale;
            tg.Children.Add(tt);
            tg.Children.Add(st);
            fe.RenderTransform = tg;
        }
        else
        {
            TransformGroup tg = fe.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
            TranslateTransform tt = tg.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
            tt.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            tt.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            ScaleTransform st = tg.Children[1] as ScaleTransform;
            st.ScaleX = e.Delta.Scale;
            st.ScaleY = e.Delta.Scale;
        }

    }
```

This will supposedly change the Scale to Delta.Scale, but how do I get Delta.Scale to be > 0 using "Pinch and Stretch"

Comment: My question is pretty much a duplicate of this except I want to enlarge instead of zoom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292019/windows-8-1-metro-app-pinch-and-zoom-an-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "instead of zooming I want to enlarge the framework element"? Do you mean you only want to enlarge the specific UIElement by fingers?

Anyway, typically you can handle pointer input and use the GestureRecognizer APIs to process gestures and manipulations in a Windows Store app. You can attached related event handle to a specific UIElement.

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Gesture-4ada6f4a) is a detailed sample code for manipulating a textblock element by tapping and sliding with the help of class GestureRecognizer.  [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59) is one more sample for reference.

Please let me know if anything not clear.

Comment: I think I am looking for the ManipulationInputProccessor Class in your links, but I am not sure how to get the second parameter UIElement target. I want the UIElement that the user is currently touching. Also "pinch and stretch" is not a gestureSetting. How do I get that event

Comment: You can refer to scenario2 in the second sample: It demos how to enlarge a rectangle control by gesture.

Comment: @FangfangWu-MSFT : the links are dead now. I tried to find the new location but with no success. Either on learn.microsoft.com or github. Can you have a look to fix this ?